# pop Up is getting disappeared when i press the backspace key

Tags: javascript

I have a pop up page in MVC and that page is coming when I call a method from the controller, but when the pop up displays in the screen if I press the backspace key, it is getting disappeared. What to do?

```
function MoveFocus()
{
    document.getElementById("Button1").focus();
    $(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
     }
  });       
}
```

I am calling this MoveFocus Funstion in each input field in the view.

Comment: you need to call this   `if (event.keyCode ==8)`  ,whether the popup is visible or not , using `is` i.e.  `is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 1):

I think stopPropagation is what your looking for...
"The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed."
[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/event_stoppropagation.asp)

```
if (event.keyCode === 8) {
     event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the Job for prevent backspace default event...

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
        var doPrevent = false;
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
            if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' &&
                 (
                     d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' ||
                     d.type.toUpperCase() === 'EMAIL' ||                         
                     d.type.toUpperCase() === 'DATE')
                 ) ||
                 d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
                doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
            }
            else {
                doPrevent = true;
            }
        }

        if (doPrevent) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```